# Could not able to SSH/(SCP the file) into local machine from the circle

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-keys, circleci, circleci-2.0

I’m trying to deploy the jar file after building from circle ci by fetching from one of the Github repo into my local machine. Here are my config file and the steps which I followed.

```
# Use the latest 2.1 version of the CircleCI pipeline process engine.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:11.0
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "a3:72:52:7d:19:e4:41:16:f1:87:ed:84:01:f9:d8:c0" // finger print ID 
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: mvn -B -DskipTests clean package
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: mvn test
      - run:
          name: Deploy Over SSH
          command: |
            scp -r /home/circleci/project/target/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar manjunathdavanam@$local_machine_ip_address:/Users/manjunathdavanam/test
workflows:
  sample:
    jobs:
      - build-and-test
```

Steps

1. I have generated an ssh key from my local machine using this command `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C  email_id`
2. After creating an ssh key,  Click on the project settings and add ssh key which is got generated from local and then after adding it will generate a fingerprint.
3. I have copied the fingerprint id and pasted it into my config.yml file.
4. I'm trying to copy the `HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`  file into my local machine `test` folder using `scp` command. `scp -r /home/circleci/project/target/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar manjunathdavanam@$local_machine_ip_address:/Users/manjunathdavanam/test`
5. I'm using mac laptop I have enabled the `remote login = true` and `allow access for all users`  in the system preferences sharing section.
6. for testing I tried to ssh from my local machine then I'm able to log in to the local machine.
7. Now, I did ssh to circle the ci machine and tried `ssh -v username@ipaddress` inside the circle ci machine but I'm getting a time out error
8. I have also checked the ssh config file inside the circle ci machine it's pointed to the right key.  `cat /home/circleci/.ssh/config`

```
Host !github.com *
  IdentitiesOnly no
  IdentityFile /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa_a373527d19e44616f18fdf4328ed8401f
```

Could you please help me here what's wrong with my config file? Why I'm not able to SCP
the file from circle ci machine to my local machine. ?

I have also raised the same in the CircleCI forum - https://discuss.circleci.com/t/could-not-able-to-ssh-scp-the-file-into-local-machine-from-the-circle/41508

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having trouble with circle CI even finding `scp` - says "command not found" no idea what is going on for such a basic functionality